# Redirect old magic [faq] links to /about instead of /help

Tags: discussion, help-center, tour, magic-links

There has been some discussion on server fault that the help homepage isn't the best place to redirect these old links.

We are thinking about redirecting [faq] links to point to the /about page but keeping all of the [faq#xxxxx] links as they are now - linking to the specific help page referenced.

The reasoning is that the /about page was specifically designed to answer the frequently asked questions of new users.

We are aware that there will be a small minority of links that intended to address other issues addressed by the old page that are not addressed by the new /about page.

Comment: Yes. This should have been done from day one.

Answer (score 4):

Directly ripped from comments on mSF:

`/about` does a serviceable job of replacing some of what `/faq` covered, and redirecting [FAQ] to `/about` is certainly more sensible than pointing it to the help center (which drops people into a sea of information without so much as a life vest).

Preserving deep links ([FAQ#xxx]) as pointers to the appropriate Help Center page also seems like The Right Thing.  If no suitable target can be found those links should also go to `/about`.

---

As part of this change it may be worth thinking about making the link to the Help Center a bit more prominent, or adding "Read more" links to certain sections of about (like on-topic/off-topic) that point to the appropriate Help Center pages.